# (for moderators) why do I have -10 reputation for "voting corrected" when I didn't even have one upvote beforehand?

Tags: discussion

[image: a picture of my reputation log. it doesn't have much because I haven't been active...]

as you can see... I made ONE post in my entire time in this stack, yet before I got a single upvote I lost points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question got two upvotes in August and September 2021. So at the time of the automatic invalidation of one upvote ("voting corrected") it had a score of two upvotes and you a reputation of 21, respectively.